# Pagination: the logic?

Tags: php

Im making a pagination system that will paginate articles in my website.

GOAL: Paginate an array of files (7 element/page)

I got across a problem that ive been troubleshooting for 5+ hours... Heres the logic side of things, correct me if im wrong.

Okay. So ive got 26 dummy articles (the alphabet) inside a folder.
Lets find the number of files in there... I will call the result: variable X.

To get the number of pagination pages, im doing the following:
X divided by 7. Obviously, this can output floats instead of integers.. So ill be rounding up the result using "cint"- which will always round upwards.
Lets call the number of pages "Z".

So me and my new friend Z want to tell some kind of function to fetch those articles. Ive made the following equations to find the start and the end of what articles I want to show.

$start = Z * 7 - 7

$end = Z * 7

Those equations generate

0 to 7 for page 1. Expected result (not reality):

a, b, c, d, e, f, g.

8 to 15 for page 2. Expected result (not reality).

h, i, j, k, l, m, n.

And so on...

So, using my superior brain (sike) I managed to generate the following output for page 1:

```html
CHOOSE PAGE: 1 2 3 4 
Youre at page 1
Theres 26 articles

Showing 0 to 7

a - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:02
b - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:04
c - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:08
d - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:10
e - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:13
f - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:15
g - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:18
```

But, wierdly enough, when I go to page 2, I get... this mess.

```html
CHOOSE PAGE: 1 2 3 4 
Youre at page 2
Theres 26 articles

Showing 7 to 14

h - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:22
i - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:24
j - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:28
k - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:31
l - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:34
m - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:37
n - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:39
o - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:42
p - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:44
q - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:47
r - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:49
s - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:51
t - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:53
u - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:55
```

...And when I go to page 3, some of the results from page 2 appears!

```html
CHOOSE PAGE: 1 2 3 4 
Youre at page 3
Theres 26 articles

Showing 14 to 21

o - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:42
p - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:54:44
q - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:47
r - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:49
s - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:51
t - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:53
u - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:55
v - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:55:57
w - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:56:00
x - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:56:03
y - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:56:05
z - Thursday, 4th of April 2019 @ 20:56:07
```

Finally, I get one last page (page 4) with the final last result from page 3.

Heres the code...

```html
<?php
$page = strip_tags($_GET['p']);
if(empty($page)){$page = "1";}

 $post_array = glob("post/*");
 $post_count = count($post_array);
 $page_num = ceil($post_count / 7);
 
 echo "CHOOSE PAGE: ";
 for($i = 1; $i<$page_num+1; $i++){
    echo "<a href=\"?p={$i}\">{$i}</a> ";
 }
 
 if($page>$page_num){
  echo "<br>error";
 } 
 elseif(!is_numeric($page)) {
  echo "<br>error";
 }
 else {echo "<br>Youre at page {$page}<br>";
 

 echo "Theres {$post_count} articles<br><br>";
 
 $start = $page * 7 - 7;
 $end = $page * 7;
 
 $post_array_sliced = array_slice($post_array, $start, $end);
 
 echo "Showing {$start} to {$end}<br><br>";
 
foreach ($post_array_sliced as $post){
  $post_name = pathinfo($post)['filename'];
  $post_date = filemtime($post);

  echo "{$post_name} - ".date('l, jS \of F Y @ H:i:s', $post_date)."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

I think this problem is caused by my awful logic skills.
Could anyone correct me, point me to docs?

Thanks alot for yall time :)

Comment: [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-slice.php) expects a _length_.

Comment: @tkausl I dont quite understand, isnt array_slice($array, 8 , 15) basically telling: "start from 8 and end at 15"?

Comment: If pages are 7, the first page should be 0-6, second page is 7-13.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

array_slice doesn't expect the first and the last index, but the first index and the length (number of elements to extract).
So you should put:

> array_slice($post_array, $start, 7);